# Eloquent relations laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table Transaction with a composite primary key  id,Nom,date and a table Cours with Nom as primary key and a transaction concerne one Cours.

How i can get Cours for a specific Transaction with Eloquent relations?

Comment: Does the table Transaction have any link to Cours yet?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Eloquent does not support composite primary keys. To find a Cours model you'll need to use multiple where clauses.

Comment: yes i did it with multiple where clauses but i have a problem of updating of the class Transaction.this class has a composite primary key or for laravel the primary key is juste the id so if i update a transaction ,all the transaction with the same id will be updated despite the nom and date are different